# Installing XCode and iOS

Tags: macos, xcode, ios

I want to get started in iPhone development, so I downloaded Xcode and the iOS SDK which was more than 2.7GB.

Now when I open the downloaded package I only have 2 files: one PDF and one .mpkg at 1.8MB only

And when I install this mpkg I can't find Xcode anywhere. Where did all the rest of the downloaded stuff go and how can I truly install Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to search in Spotlight (cmd space) for Xcode? It should be there.

If you're able to open it, keep it in the dock (right click the icon in the dock, options...).

Answer (score 4):

I think Apple distributes software using `.dmg` disk images. Files on disk images can be hidden. If you were able to install it, it's all good.

Xcode is in `/Developer/Applications`, along with the rest of the developer tools.